# Core Data - Select specific Column

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, swift

I'm trying to select only some columns from my database, but still yes it returns me all. I'm doing the following:

```
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Father")
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = NSArray(objects: "id", "name")

        let sorterByName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = NSArray(object: sorterByName)
```

i have the following columns:

- id
- name
- address
- age

I need select only `id` and `name` but returns all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in Apple's documentation for `propertiesToFetch`:

> This value is only used if resultType is set to
>   NSDictionaryResultType.